# Open an external link in cuba app programmatically

Tags: vaadin, cuba-platform

I would like to open an external link by clicking a button. I have the following code in the action method of the button:

```
((com.vaadin.ui.Button) myCubaButton.unwrap(com.vaadin.ui.Button)).UI.page.open('https://www.google.de', '_blank')
```

Is there a more cuba like way to open an external link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use showWebPage() method of AbstractWindow / WindowManager:

```
showWebPage("https://google.com", ParamsMap.of("target", "_blank"));
```